# Python Stack Iteration, best practices

Tags: python

What is the specific method to iterate a stack in python. is the best practice to use a for loop just like to iterate a list?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you mean by "stack" and "iterate"?  Perhaps show an example for-loop that you think is not quite right.

Comment: in C# language we get an iterator object to iterate a list or a stack . in python when iterating a stack is there a good practice?

Comment: I Think you'll find "best practice" is heavily tied to purpose, you can iterate using `list comprehensions`, `itertools.chain`, `generator sequences`, `map` and many more. The most readable solution is usually the best, if speed is an issue then use what is fastest while still maintaining readability.

Comment: can any one provide a working example?

Comment: see my comment below, there's pretty much well explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have said, python doesn't really have a built-in stack datatype, per se-- but you can use a list to emulate one.

When using a list as a stack, you can model the first-in-last-out behavior with append() as push and pop() as pop, as julio.alegria describes.

If you want to use that list in a for-loop, but still have it behave in the FILO fashion you can reverse the order of the elements with this slice syntax: `[::-1]`.

Example:

```
for element in stack[::-1]:
    print element
```

If you're using a custom class that implements a stack, just as long as it has `__iter__()` and `next()` methods defined you can use it in list comprehensions, for loops, or whatever.

That way you can implement a custom iterator that removes items as it iterates over it, just as it should with a proper stack.

Example:

```
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
    def push(self,n):
        self.data.append(n)
    def pop(self):
        return self.data.pop()
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if len(self.data)>0:
            return self.pop()
        else:
            raise StopIteration

filo = Stack()
filo.push(1)
filo.push(2)
filo.push(3)

for i in filo:
    print i
```

Comment: Smart idea for the `statck[::-1]`

Comment: @Xin Python's slicing semantics create shallow copies, so this is actually very inefficient for iteration cases. If you need a (shallow) copy, it's perfect, if you just need to iterate in reverse, the `reversed` function is more performant.

Answer (score 12):

If your stack can potentially grow to large proportions, you should absolutely not be using a `List` or a custom stack class. Raymond Hettinger has already done the work for you and written the wonderful `collections.deque`. The `deque` is a list like data structure that supports constant time appends and pops from both ends.

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>>
>>> stack = deque()
>>> stack.append(1)
>>> stack.append(2)
>>> stack.append(3)
>>> print stack
deque([1,2,3])
```

By then appropriately using `deque.pop()` and `deque.popleft()` you can acheive both FILO and FIFO respectively. You can also iterate over it with `for item in stack` if you want FIFO or `for item in reversed(stack)` for FILO, which will generate a memory efficient reverse iterator.

Comment: In a better world, this answer would be the accepted answer.

Comment: Why not use a `List`, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Xin the `List` type has a fixed underlying size. In the simplest case, if you attempt to append an item that requires more memory that is currently allocated, a new, larger memory space is allocated, the existing `List` is copied into this space, and only then is your new element appended. This makes appending to a `List` a potentially O(n) operation (due to the copy). The `deque` is consistently O(1) for both append and pop (at both ends no less).

Answer (score 3):

In Python, unlike other prog. languages ​​like C++ (STL), we do not have predefined data structure `Stack`, we just have a regular `List`.

So, if you want to iterate your "Stack" as a regular List, you can just simply have to make something like:

```
for item in reversed(my_list): # to preserve LIFO
    # do something with item
    # ...
```

Now, if you want your List to behave as a Stack (LIFO: Last In First Out), you could use the predefined list functions `append` and `pop`:

```
>>> stack = [1, 2]
>>> stack.append(3)
>>> stack.append(4)
>>> stack
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> stack.pop()
4
>>> stack
[1, 2, 3]
```

More about this in http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#using-lists-as-stacks

Comment: `.append()`, `.pop()` work at the end of the list. You should probably use `for item in reversed(my_list)` to preserve LIFO order.